# Print Specific Rows and Columns in Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am having trouble printing certain values within my CSV.

I have a file that has 9 columns

```
Record_id   Month   Day   Year  Location_id   Animal_id  Sex   Length   Weight
```

and over 1000 rows.

I want to print Month , Day , and Year columns when the year is equivalent to 2002.

Because I have a lot of data I decided to only work with the first 5 rows where year is equal to 2002.

This is my code:

```
data.df.iloc[0:5, 1:4]
```

With this I can print the first 5 rows and the 3 columns I desire. However I can't figure out how to filter the year to be 2002

Comment: Please revise your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `df.loc[df.Year==2002,:].iloc[0:5, 1:4]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can start by getting all the rows where year equal to 2002
with

```
filtered_data = df[df["Year"]==2002]
```

then you can apply your code to get only the first five rows and the three selected columns with

```
filtered_data.iloc[0:5, 1:4]
```